# How to stop Eclipse formatter from adding trailing whitespaces in Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, whitespace, javadoc, formatter

I noticed an odd behavior of the Eclipse formatter (Strg+Alt+F) when running it on a piece of code like this:

```
/**
 * bar
 *
 * @return nothing
 */
Object foo() {
    return null;
}
```

It will **add** a trailing space character here:

```
/**
 * bar
 * <--- this line has a trailing space now!
 * @return nothing
 */
Object foo() {
    return null;
}
```

I know how to configure Eclipse to remove trailing whitespace, but it there a way to stop the formatter from adding it in the first place?

Comment: Just curious, but is there a specific reason why the space *can't* be there? Having the space there allows comment addition to already be offset from the asterisks.

Comment: This space character causes warnings with certain code style tools like checkstyle

Comment: According to the Oracle documentation, "@returns" is not a valid JavaDoc tag, but "@return" is. _That_ should have been reported by CheckStyle. The default configuration of checkstyle should never be used in a project, because it creates to much noise with no benefit.

Comment: Any updates on this? We're having the same problem and Eclipse is ramdomly adding or removing the whitespace on save. Drives us nuts.

Comment: @user871611 This was at least partially fixed in Eclipse Luna - Applying the code formatter will no longer add the trailing whitespace. However, it will not remove it either. I am not sure about auto-format on save, but I assume it is the same behavior as manually applying the formatter.

Comment: We're using Luna. But our problem is that the auto-save function  (with formatting enabled, etc.) is randomly adding or removing the whitespace. Seems like a bug in Eclipse. Calling format or cleanup manually behaves correct.

Comment: @user871611 Ah yes, now that you mention it, I remember that it did the same for me: Randomly inserting and removing the trailing whitespaces. Seems to be a weird race condition, which is why I ended up disabling auto-format on save. Hopefully Mars will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I guess we'll also disable it and wait for better times.

Answer (score 2):

You can just go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions and configure it to remove trailing whitespace.

In order to do that right-click on your project and go to Properties -> Java Editor -> Save Actions. From there you can enable project specific settings and configure it to remove trailing whitespace (among other useful things).

Comment: Thanks. Like I said, I know how to configure Eclipse to automatically remove it. What I am interested in is how to tell the formatter to **not insert** this space character.

Comment: This does not answer the OP (and mine) issue

Answer (score -3):

Under **Java** -> **Code Style** -> **Formatter**.  **Edit** the active profile (you may need to save a new one) On the **Comments** tab under the **Javadoc comment settings** area you should uncheck **Blank line before Javadoc tags**.

Was so annoying before I found this.